# gcloud ssh stack at authentication, plus incorrect name

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I am trying to login to my VM on google cloud using the following command (on Win 7):

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=<zone_name> --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="1080" --ssh-flag="-N" <host_name>
```

It opens Putty windows with the following info:

```
Using username "some.local.name".
Authenticating with public key "SOMEDOMAIN\some.local.name@localhostname"
```

And does not move beyond this screen. It looks like it is using my local machine name and username instead relevant to google cloud. I wonder how I can fix it?

Also what are these flags `--ssh-flag="-D"` and `-ssh-flag="-N"`. I cannot find explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh, `--ssh-flag` passing the argument directly into PuTTY. You can look at PuTTY's help to see what `-D` and `-N` mean.

Does doing just `gcloud compute ssh <host_name>` work? I am assume by `<host_name>` you mean the Google Cloud Compute VM instance name.

Comment: Yes, the following worked: `gcloud compute ssh --zone=<zone_name> --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="1080"  <host_name>` and yes by `host_name` I meant instance name.

Comment: Do you know how change username used by gcloud to login?